# swiftでグラフ機能を実現させるための学習方法について

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

初心者でswiftを文法から学習しています。
教本で一通り基本構文を学習した状態です。

現在は「カレンダー機能」と「グラフ機能」を搭載したアプリを
試行錯誤で作っております。

皆様にご助言を頂きたいことは、
上記のようにswiftでグラフ機能を実現させるための学習方法についてです。

いま、躓いている点は以下の通りです。

「グラフ機能」をつけるにあたり、ゼロからプログラミングをするのは、
まだ厳しい状況なので、ライブラリを使おうと思います。

よく使われているライブラリで、

BEMSimpleLineGraph
PNChart for iOS
Core Plot

これらがあると思います。

しかし、一番シンプルなBEMSimpleLineGraphですら、
グラフの「グ」の字も書けません。

具体的には、以下の点で躓いております。

・グラフ表現するための各ファイルがどういう風に繋がって構成されているのか？

・各ファイル（特にViewController）に書かれている構文において、
　その意味が学習した基本構文ではほとんど理解できない。

（以下は、意味や目的などは理解しており、実際に設定も完了したが、
　その設定方法においては不安が残っている点）

CocoaPodsでBEMSimpleLineGraphなどのライブラリをインストールしました。
また、CocoaPodsを用いずに、直接インストールする方法も実現できましたが、
どちらもフワッと理解しているような状態です。

以上を踏まえて、今後、どのように取り組めば、
「グラフ機能」を搭載したアプリを実現できるかご教授頂ければと思います。

●「本で学習する場合」
アマゾンで調べた限り、上記のようなグラフアプリに関する本や、
ライブラリに関する本は見つかりませんでした。
もし比較的、初心者でも理解しやすい教本があればご教授ください。

●「ネットのブログや公式サイトの解説で学習する場合」
そこに書かれている内容がまだ理解できない状態なら、
やはり再度、基本構文を学習し直すべきでしょうか？

●「スクールに通う場合」
経済的に、また時間的に厳しいのですが、
例えば、上記のような目的と不明点をピンポイントで質問して、
それを個別で教えてくれるスクールや家庭教師などはあるのでしょうか？

漠然とした質問になっておりますが、
効果的な、効率的な学習方法について何かございましたら、
ご教授のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

以下、参考にしたサイト

【iOS】BEMSimpleLineGraphを使ってiOSでグラフ描画をする方法
http://tech.admax.ninja/2014/10/16/how-to-use-bemsimplelinegraph/

Comment: そもそも「Swiftでサードパーティライブラリを導入して開発する」ということ自体、初心者にはかなりハードルが高いと思います。ですから、ライブラリ自体の初心者向けの本や解説というのは期待しないほうがよいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうですね。書籍では期待できないですよね。

Answer (score 0):

私が知っているのは、Core Plotだけですが、これは、最初の人には、とっつきにくいでしょう。
また、Objective-C用なので、SwiftからObjective-Cを呼び出す技をマスターしている必要があります。
　Core Plotで、かけるグラフの種類は、何種類か決まっていますので、あなたが書きたいグラフの対象が、サポートされていないなら、Core Plotは、除外するしかないでしょう。

Core Plotの場合、サンプルソースがあるので、それを見ながら、オンラインドキュメントのクラスの説明を読んで、トライアルをなんどもシミュレータでやる必要があります。
　Google検索はするがクラスリファレンスを読まない主義だ、とか、delegateの理解が出来ていない人には、おそらく歯がたたないでしょう。

Comment: とても参考になりました。特に、delegateの理解を深めるというのは参考になります。ありがとうございました。